# System automation = Website dashboard panel + with mobile app and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, katalon-studio

I create an IT system for my own needs and I have a question for you. Which tool or how to write automation tests if I have a website (Admin panel -> Dashboard) connected with a mobile application (I receive e-mail notifications) and a correlated dedicated Wordpress plugin which is also related to the mobile application and my admin Website. Is it possible to automate such a process as a whole in some way?
In the sense of an example scenario. Adds a user to Wordpress, I get a notification on the mobile application -> the information in my Dashboard is automatically confirmed that the person has been added as a user.

Would not it be better to add separate tests of each subpage in a "classic way" eg. checking the main functionality using Selenium or another automation framework?

Could someone experienced guide me in which direction to go, so that I could sensibly automatically verify my system?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Greetings
Chris